# Error 3022 Cannot add a duplicate value because of a key constrain

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert a value into a table and i am getting an error 3022(It says that there might be a problem with a relation, a key or index). I have not created the table myself but i found out the specific column that triggers the error. I have checked that its not a key, index and there is not a relation to that table that depends on that specific column.
Is there anything i can do to avoid that error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No offense intended, but I tend to believe the application. There must be an index or a relation that you believe is innocuous but is actually the cause of the error. Therefore, I recommend the following:

In Access, with all tables closed, click the "Database Tools" tab on the ribbon and then click the "Database Documenter" button in the "Analyze" section of the ribbon bar. In the dialog box that appears, place a checkmark beside the table in question and then click the "Options..." button. In the options dialog, make sure that the highest level of detail is selected:

[image: Options.png]

Click "OK" to close the Print Table Definition dialog, then click "OK" again to run the Documenter report.

Study the report carefully. If you don't see the cause of your error then, in the "Data" section of the ribbon, click "PDF or XPS". Save the report as PDF, upload the PDF to a site like [wikisend.com](http://wikisend.com), and then post the link here so we can retrieve the report.

Oh, and update your question to tell us exactly how you are trying to insert the data, and in what field(s). If you are using an INSERT query, post the *actual* SQL code you are trying to use.